# How to invoke a Lambda from another Lambda correctly

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I try to invoke a “child” lambda from a “parent” lambda

The example of code is very simple as below (I am using Serverless framework).

child_lambda

```
const mainHandler = async (event, context) => {
    console.log('event: ', JSON.stringify(event));    
    return context.functionName;
  };
export const handler = mainHandler;
```

parent_lambda

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk';
const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

const invokeLambda = async () => {
  let sampleData = { number1: 1, number2: 2 };

  let params = {
    FunctionName: 'child_lambda',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(sampleData),
    Qualifier: '1'
  };

  try {
    await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('invokeLambda :: Error: ' + e);
  }
};

const mainHandler = async (event, context) => {
  console.log('event: ', JSON.stringify(event));
  await invokeLambda();
  return context.functionName;
};

export const handler = mainHandler;
```

serverless.yml

```
parent_lambda:
    handler: handlers/lambda/parent_lambda.handler
    name: dev_parent_lambda
    iamRoleStatements:
      - Effect: "Allow"        
        Action:
          - lambda: InvokeFunction
          - lambda: InvokeAsync   
        Resource: "*"
    events:
      - http:
          path: test/invokeLambda
          method: GET

child_lambda:
    handler: handlers/lambda/child_lambda.handler
    name: dev_child_lambda
```

I run the parent from Postman and the result is

> ResourceNotFoundException: Function not found:
> arn:aws:lambda:xxxx:xxxxx:function:dev_child_lambda

I tried to trigger the child_lambda from an S3 event, it worked fine, but never work with `invoke` as AWS SDK.

Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: do you have lambda versioning enabled? i see you are passing [Qualifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax) as 1 , meaning you are trying to invoke the lambda of version 1 ? if not, we can remove that , so, it will simply call the $latest

Comment: BaluVyamajala Yes, removing that qualifier, it worked like charm.

Comment: Ideally, one Lambda function would not synchronously invoke another Lambda function.

Comment: @jarmod : my scenario is S3 event trigger a lambda A, and another lambda B also need that lambda A, so I decided to use "invoke" to call lambda A to avoid redundant code. If you know a better approach, please help.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean, but typical patterns include async Lambda invocation, or fan-out using SNS (so multiple Lambdas can be triggered by a single event), or Lambda to SNS to Lambda for chaining, or Step Functions if more complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, code given in the question is perfect except the [Qualifier](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html) parameter

Qualifier is used to

> Specify a version or alias to invoke a published version of the
> function.

In this case, lambda is not versioned. Hence we just need to remove qualifier .

```
const invokeLambda = async () => {
  let sampleData = { number1: 1, number 2: 2 };

  let params = {
    FunctionName: 'child_lambda',
    Payload: JSON.stringify(sampleData)
  };

  try {
    await lambda.invoke(params).promise();
    return true;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('invokeLambda :: Error: ' + e);
  }
};
```

Comment: does it leverage api-gateway cache? so that multiple lambda functions can use the results with minimum invocations

Answer (score 0):

[Lambda Asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html)

> Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) invoke functions asynchronously to process events. When you invoke a function asynchronously, you don't wait for a response from the function code. You hand off the event to Lambda and Lambda handles the rest.

In that case, I would simply chain the lambdas using AWS lambda destinations. Supported destinations:

- Amazon SQS – sqs:SendMessage
- Amazon SNS – sns:Publish
- Lambda – lambda:InvokeFunction
- EventBridge – events:PutEvents

[Configuring destinations for asynchronous invocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invocation-async.html#invocation-async-destinations)

[Introducing AWS Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/)